# Applying for a second Schengen Visa within 2 months.

Tags: visas, schengen, france, sweden

I visited France on a Schengen visa in September for 12 days (visa obtained in July). I would like to visit Sweden now for 5 days in October. Can I apply for another Schengen visa so soon? Do i need to wait for X days before applying for another Schengen visa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to wait.

- Your stay on any combination of short-stay visa must comply with the 90/180 rule. No problem with that yet.
- The fact that you came to France **and left again** will make you appear a lower overstay risk on your next application.
- They like to see applicants with a stable and well-paid job. Visiting again **after just one month** might look unusual in this regard, but it is perfectly normal that people have more than 12 days of vacation per year.
- They will have compared your first itinerary with your financial means (your income and expenditures, not just the balance). They will do so again and consider that you spent money in September.

The timing of the new application is not a problem if your circumstances are unchanged and you can afford it.